# Mongo db query , take any userinput and search according to those

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

I’m new to mongo DB. What will be the schema or schemas what is user inputted, how we can recognize those in our code, or rather what will be the query (using javascript ).

**Question:**

Suppose we have a book schema and saved some books in the database, now we have to make a post api `/getParticularBooks`
take any input and use it as a condition to fetch books that satisfy that condition

**e.g**

if body had `{ name: “hi”}` then you would fetch the books with this name
if body had `{ year: 2020}` then you would fetch the books in this year 
Or maybe the both at same time 
hence the condition will differ based on what you input in the request body

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a function which verify if the user request body doesn't have any input property which isn't define in your schema.
I would do it like that

```
const verifyProperty = (user_request_body) => {
 const properties  = [list of your schema property];

 for(let i in properties){
  const string = properties[i]

  if(!(string in user_request_body)) 
   return false;
}
 return true;
}
```

And now, based on the return value of the verifyProperty function, you can send a query or return an error message.

```
if(verifyProperty(req.body) == false){
 return res.json({message: "Invalid properties"})
}

const data = await Books.find(req.body);
return res.json({data})
```

In order to use await, your function must be async